Two indicator pine-script v6
I have two indicators with the v5 update and I converted them to v6. One of the indicators is on the chart and the other is in a separate window. After the update, the two indicators appear on the chart. What is the correct code to separate the two indicators? Thank you.
I want the first indicator on the chart and the second indicator in a separate window.

Without any code it´s difficult to tell, but please read this about force_overlay, which controls where an indicator is shown, in the chart or in a pane.
